# Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 keeps crashing

Tags: windows-7, crash, internet-explorer-11

I have several units that are experiencing Internet Explorer 11 crashing. 
They all have Windows 7. 
I have run all Windows updates – No change. 
I have defaulted the browser – No change.

I see the below error in the logs:

```
Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.18666, time stamp: 0x58f30f27
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23796, time stamp: 0x59028db3
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000ce8fb
Faulting process id: 0x23f4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d408951d83f6e2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 64f99a72-7488-11e8-b368-3464a9393db8
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a dump of the process?  To do so, download, procdump.exe to C:\dumps, then in an admin command prompt run: `C:\dumps\procdump.exe -ma -i C:\dumps`.  Recreate the issue a couple of times and you should have potentially 4 dumps.  For some reason, procdump creates 2,  but the first of each repro should be enough.  `procdump -u` will remove the registry keys and in effect "uninstall" Procdump. Procdump can be obtained from here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

Comment: See this page to repair IE11....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Webroot, disable the Web Shield extension. That is causing the IE and Chrome crashes.

Comment: I am attempting this solution right now. I just created a policy that has the extension turned off. I will update with the results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the exact same problems with Webroot and IE11 w/275+ workstations. I left Web Shield enabled and then disabled Activate browser extensions. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eg2x.png)I know this fixes the problem. But now I'm working on adding more of the individual modules back in to see which one is the culprit.